# Discord.py slash-command ctx.send()

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

everyone having a small issue with the Slash commands.
The idea is that I fetch an Array of Assetdata convert each into an embedded and then send the embedded. If there is an image it will show an image and if a .mp4 is linked to the asset it will convert the mp4 to gif and then attache the file locally with file = discord.File(). This all worked just fine bevor moving to Slash commands. For some reason, the slash command wants to send a response bevor receiving all the data. This is an issue because the gif processing takes time or if a large sum of data is requested the request takes longer. The function works fine if have a single asset to display and an Image.

So my question is how do I get ctx.send() to wait??

Thanks in Advance everyone!

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)


@slash.slash(
    name="assetsearch",
    description="Sends a Message",
    guild_ids=[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX], #Hidden for StackOverflow
    options = [
        create_option(
            name = "searchtype",
            description = "Please choose how you would like to search for an Asset.",
            required = True,
            option_type = 3,
            choices = [
                create_choice(
                    name = "Search by Asset Id",
                    value = "id"
                ),
                create_choice(
                    name = "Search by Collection",
                    value = "colec"
                ),
                create_choice(
                    name = "Search by Accountname",
                    value = "acc"
                ),
                create_choice(
                    name = "Search by Asset Name",
                    value = 'match'
                )
            ]
        ),
        create_option(
            name = "searchterm",
            description = "Please enter an Asset Id, an Account name, the name of an Asset or the Collection name.",
            required = True,
            option_type = 3
            ),

        create_option(
            name = "amount",
            description = "Please enter how many Assets you would like to display.",
            required = True,
            option_type = 3
            ),
    ],
)

async def _assetsearch(ctx:SlashContext, searchtype: str, searchterm: str, amount: str):
    response = await getAssetData(searchtype, searchterm, amount) #Fetches an Array of AssetData, async function
    for asset in response:
        nftEmbed, nftFile = await __formatMessage(asset) #formats the message, converts mp4 from website to gif, returns the gif and ebeded
        print(nftEmbed,nftFile)
        await ctx.send(embed=nftEmbed, file=nftFile) #send the embeded and gif, ISSUE!!!
        if os.path.isfile('Nft.gif'): os.remove("Nft.gif")
    response = ""
```

Working Function bevor using slash-command

```
    if msg.startswith('$search'):
        try:
            searchType = msg.split(",")[1]
        except:
            searchType = 'match'
        try:
            searchTerm = msg.split(",")[2]
        except:
            searchTerm = 'abcd'
        try:
            searchLimit = msg.split(",")[3]
        except:
            searchLimit = '1'
        response = getAssetData(searchType,searchTerm,searchLimit)
        for asset in response:
            nftEmbed, file = __formatMessage(asset)
            await message.channel.send(embed=nftEmbed, file=file)
            if os.path.isfile('Nft.gif'): os.remove("Nft.gif")
        response = ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The Slashcomands are expecting a response within 3s if you are working with an API in the background and then precessing data this could become a criterium you cant meet consistently. This is why you would have the Bot itself respond directly upon request. Once you are done with processing your data you can respond normaly

```
async def _slashcomandfunction(ctx:SlashContext, str:otherparameters,):
    message = await ctx.send('Sometext') #Direct respond
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed, file=file) #Actual message
```

If you don't want the Bots message

```
message = await ctx.send('Sometext',delete_after=1)
```

...or edit the message the Bot sent.

```
message = await ctx.send('Sometext')
await message.edit(content="newcontent")
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use asyncio?

import asyncio

await asyncio.sleep(number)

Or is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried that but that sadly did not work. The issue is that discord expects a response after 3s. I posted the answer above. Cheers, thanks for your input.